# ZeroMQ: swift-code with SwiftyZeroMQ .recv() still blocks GUI text update even after poller.poll( pollIn)

Tags: swift, zeromq

Using the `PAIR/PAIR` pattern, I want the client to send some messages, and the receiving server to display the received messages as they come in. I have a client sending via python code:

```
import zmq
import time

context = zmq.Context()
port = "5555"
context = zmq.Context()
socket = context.socket(zmq.PAIR)
socket.connect("tcp://localhost:%s" % port)

m=""

while m!="eof":
    m=input(">")
    socket.send_string(m)
```

and a server that is a swift GUI app, using the SwiftyZeroMQ library, displaying the received text in a textview as they come in, snippet:

```
import Cocoa
import SwiftyZeroMQ

@NSApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var window: NSWindow!
    @IBOutlet var alert_txt: NSTextView!

    func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ aNotification: Notification) {
        // Insert code here to initialize your application
        do {
            self.alert_txt.string="wait..."

            let endpoint     = "tcp://*:5555"
            let textToBeSent = "swift: get"
            let context      = try SwiftyZeroMQ.Context()

            let receiver      = try context.socket(.pair)
            try receiver.bind(endpoint)

            let poller = SwiftyZeroMQ.Poller()
            try poller.register(socket: receiver, flags: .pollIn)

            var sdct=true

            while sdct{
                let socks = try poller.poll(timeout: 1000)
                for subscriber in socks.keys {
                    if socks[subscriber] == SwiftyZeroMQ.PollFlags.pollIn {
                        let text = try subscriber.recv(options: .dontWait)
                        print("received '\(text)'")
                        self.alert_txt.string+=text!
                        if text=="eof"
                        {
                            sdct=false
                        }
                    }
                }
            }            
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
    }

    func applicationWillTerminate(_ aNotification: Notification) {
        // Insert code here to tear down your application
    }
}
```

however, the swift GUI displays the spinning beachball, the text field is not being updated until "eof" was received; the `print("received '\(text)'")` works and I can see it update in the xcode console output. I assume there's something wrong with my code involving the `poller`, but I haven't been able to fix the issue. In this `PAIR/PAIR` mode, my test code for the receiving end using python works as expected:

```
import time
import zmq

context = zmq.Context()


port = "5555"
context = zmq.Context()
socket = context.socket(zmq.PAIR)
socket.bind("tcp://*:%s" % port)

msg=""
while msg !="eof":
    msg = socket.recv()
    msg=msg.decode("utf-8")
    print(msg,"\n=========")
```

Comment: is hte issue resolved?

Answer (score 0):

As it is, your `applicationDidFinishLaunching` doesn't return until you receive "eof", so macOS thinks your app has stalled - hence the beachball.

Try moving your `while sdct { ... }` into a separate function and call it on a background thread. Arrange for eventual UI updates to happen back on the main thread.